# How to read context of two spinners and send both to next activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, spinner

I have two spinners and I want to grab the values that the user chooses and send it to the next activity. My first activity is titled IO and I create the spinners and get the data from the selections in my onCreate.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_io);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Spinner locationSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(IO.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.busStops));
    myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    locationSpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    location = locationSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    Spinner destinationSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(IO.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.busStops));
    myAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    destinationSpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter2);
    destination = destinationSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
}
```

I tried sending the data in another method titled sendRoutes where I created an intent but it didn't work and I was wondering how to do this.

Comment: share part of code that you try to go to another activity

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to open your activity on a button click then,

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String destination = destinationSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String location = locationSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("destination",destination);
                intent.putExtra("location",location);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

You are passing destination and location values to `NextActivity` by intent.

Answer (score 0):

in IO Activity definition Intent :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(IO.this,SecondActivity.class);
location = locationSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
destination = destinationSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
intent.putExtra(KEY_DEST,destination);
intent.putExtra(KEY_LOC,location);
startActivity(intent);
```

in SecondActivity get two parameters in onCreate :

```
String destination = getInetent().getExtras.getString(KEY_DEST);
String location = getInetent().getExtras.getString(KEY_LOC);
```